# Download Files with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, openrowset

Is it possible to download .xml files using Sql Server 2008?

I will use those files for read an UUID from a bill.

I can read .xml with `OPENROWSET(BULK '''+@path+''', SINGLE_BLOB)`, this is easy because these files are into my personal directory, but I have many files in a server.

I want download these files using a query into Sql Server, when a file is downloaded i go to use `OPENROWSET` for read the information.

Comment: this cannot be done as far as I know.

Comment: You can use `xp_cmdshell` to call external programs, or you could create an SSIS package which executes the programs you need.  Usually I would expect to have an SSIS package itself do everything, or, if this were a demand-based download, for a service broker to be written to respond to tasks sent to it to retrieve external files and load them.  This is somewhat outside what an RDBMS does and more what an application does.

Comment: Thanks, i go to try.